# docker sonarqube process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1

Tags: docker, sonarqube, dockerhub

I tried to install sonarqube with docker like below

```
sudo docker pull sonarqube
sudo docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube
```

when i run `sudo docker ps -a` the status always exited

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                    COMMAND                 STATUS                        PORTS               
c76d3a0ee7db   sonarqube                                             "/opt/sonarqube/bin/…"     Exited (0) 26 seconds ago    
aa6eebb7d9d5   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.0   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"     Up 2 minutes                 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp
```

the docker logs

> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:33739]
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]:
> /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
> could not find java in ES_JAVA_HOME at
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/java
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
> 2023.01.20 08:13:04 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

Comment: Did you installed some plugins for elasticsearch in sonarqube? I started sonarqube only, it is running since 2 minutes and is woking. However I think it is a network problem, try to put these containers inside the same network and retry.
1) create a network `docker network create -d bridge my-network`
2) add network to container `docker network connect my-network sonarqube` and `docker network connect my-network elasticsearch`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I launched this on a t2.micro instance. Please try this on an instance having a minimum of 2GB memory and 20GB volume.

```
                 Name                                   Command                State      Ports
```

---

docker-compose-project-for-ci-cd-pipeline_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up         5432/tcp
jenkins                                          /sbin/tini -- /usr/local/b ...   Exit 137
nexus                                            /opt/sonatype/nexus/bin/ne ...   Exit 1
sonarqube                                        /opt/sonarqube/docker/entr ...   Exit 0
root@ip-172-31-91-161:/home/ubuntu/cicd/Docker-Compose-Project-for-CI-CD-Pipeline# docker logs sonarqube
2023.03.30 17:45:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2023.03.30 17:45:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:41673]
2023.03.30 17:45:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2023.03.30 17:45:46 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.03.30 17:45:51 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 137
2023.03.30 17:45:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.03.30 17:45:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2023.03.30 17:55:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2023.03.30 17:55:02 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:42417]
2023.03.30 17:55:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2023.03.30 17:55:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.03.30 17:55:07 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 137
2023.03.30 17:55:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.03.30 17:55:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped

After modifying instance

```
                 Name                                   Command               State                                                  Ports
```

---

docker-compose-project-for-ci-cd-pipeline_db_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp
jenkins                                          /sbin/tini -- /usr/local/b ...   Up      0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp,:::50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp,
0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp,:::8443->8443/tcp
nexus                                            /opt/sonatype/nexus/bin/ne ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp,:::8081->8081/tcp
sonarqube                                        /opt/sonarqube/docker/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp,:::9000->9000/tcp